# Structural types in scala

Tags: scala, typeclass

If I have a class like this

```
class CanFlyType[T <: {type thing <: Bird}](t : T) {
  def flySpeed() = {
    println(t)
  }
}
```

What can you pass in the constructor to create this class? I tried passing this

```
class Species
class Animal extends Species
class Tiger extends Animal
abstract class Bird (name : String) extends Species {
  val birdName = name
  val flySpeed : Int
}

class Sparrow(name : String) extends Bird(name) {
  val flySpeed = 30
}


val sparrow : Bird1 = new Sparrow("Robbin")

val canFly = new CanFlyType(sparrow)
```

But I get an error. I know we can achieve this in other ways, but I just want to know if you can use type in a structural type way and the difference between the above and

```
class CanFly1[T <: Bird1](bird : T) {
  def flySpeed() = {
    println(bird.flySpeed)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you specify `[T <: {type thing <: Bird}]`, you are telling the compiler to look for a type with a *type member* called thing, which itself must be a subclass of `Bird`.

The following fixes the issue:

```
class Species
class Animal extends Species
class Tiger extends Animal
abstract class Bird (name : String) extends Species {
  val birdName = name
  val flySpeed : Int
}

class Sparrow(name : String) extends Bird(name) {
  type thing = this.type
  val flySpeed = 30
}


val sparrow : Sparrow = new Sparrow("Robbin")

val canFly = new CanFlyType(sparrow)

class CanFlyType[T <: {type thing <: Bird}](t : T) {
  def flySpeed() = {
    println(t)
  }
}
```

Note that is probably *NOT* what you want to do in practice. You probably are looking to simply simply constrain your `CanFlyType[T <: Bird]`.